# How to describe a schema for many-to-many GrhapQl relationships with custom properties?

Tags: graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

How to describe a schema for many-to-many GrhapQl relationships with custom properties?

Hi guys! I have the following tables:

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        Product                         |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| name        | varchar(255) |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        Nutrient                         |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| name        | varchar(255) |                            |
| unit        | varchar(255) |                            |
| alias       | varchar(255) |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                  Product_To_Nutrient                    |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| nutrientId  | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY    |
| productId   | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY    |
| amount      | int(11)      |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

To get nutrients, I use dataloader.

How can I describe my schema so that I can run the following query and get the AMOUNT for each nutrient? Or maybe I need to rebuild my database, if so, which architecture would be optimal? Thank you in advance for your advice :)

```
    query Product {
     getProducts {
      id,
      name,
      nutrients: {
       name,
       unit,
       alias,
       AMOUNT
      }
    }
```

My stack: TypeOrm, TypeGraphQL, MicroOrm, NodeJs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- rename the `Product_To_Nutrient` table to `ingredients` (just for convenience)
- and move the `unit` property from the `nutritient` to your `ingredient` as it's important to know the `quantity` in `units`. (In the current situation, if you would ever have to update the `unit`, you also have to update all `ingredients` using that `nutritient`.

Querying with GraphQL, you'll have to do through the `ingredients`

```
query Product {
  getProducts {
    id,
    name,
    ingredients: {
      nutrient: {
        id,
        name,
        alias
      },
      quantity,
      unit
    }
  }
}
```

To load the `ingredient`, when querying the products, you can make it [an 'eager' relationship](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/eager-and-lazy-relations).

Use the `Dataloader` to load all the `nutrients` linked to the `ingredient`.